# ASP.net core Entity Framework Eager Loading

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, eager-loading

Good evening.

I am building a small web API for project management.

Each Project is split into many Tasks.

Eventually I attempt to access the Project object(master) from the Task object(slave) but the GET request(on a Task) gets no response via postman or an an incomplete response via chrome, just like this:

GET /api/task/1 :

```
{
"id": 1,
"name": "Task A",
"description": "Primary task",
"priority": 0,
"state": 0,
"projectId": 1,
"project": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Project 1",
    "description": "First project",
    "deadline": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "clientId": 0,
    "tasks": [
```

I'll present the model, context and controller classes and I wish to get your assistance on how to correctly indicate to EF to include the Project object corresponding to the foreign key field in the Task.

Here are the class for the Project model:

```
//Project.cs:

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace ProjectManagementAPI.Models
{
    public class Project
    {
        public Project()
        {
            Tasks = new List<Task>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public String Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime Deadline { get; set; }
        public int ClientId { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And for Task:

```
//Task.cs

namespace ProjectManagementAPI.Models
{
    public enum STATE { Pending, Started, Blocked, Finished }

    public class Task
    {
        public Task()
        {
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public String Description { get; set; }
        public int Priority { get; set; }
        public STATE State { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ProjectId")]
        public int ProjectId { get; set; }
        public Project Project { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The Context class details the relationship via Fluent API:

```
//ProjectManagementDBEntities.cs

namespace ProjectManagementAPI.Models
{
    public class ProjectManagementDBEntities : DbContext
    {
        public ProjectManagementDBEntities(DbContextOptions<ProjectManagementDBEntities> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Task>()
                .HasOne(p => p.Project)
                .WithMany(b => b.Tasks)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
        }

        public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Project controller class (update and delete controls omitted):

```
//ProjectController.cs

namespace ProjectManagementAPI.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ProjectController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ProjectManagementDBEntities _context;

        public ProjectController(ProjectManagementDBEntities context)
        {
            _context = context;

        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Project> GetAll()
        {
            return _context.Projects.ToList();
        }


        [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetProject")]
        public IActionResult GetById(long id)
        {
            var project = _context.Projects.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == id);
            if (project == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return new ObjectResult(project);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create([FromBody] Project project)
        {
            if (project == null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            project.Tasks = new List<Task>();

            _context.Projects.Add(project);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            return CreatedAtRoute("GetProject", new { id = project.Id }, project);
        }
}
```

In the Task controller, I use LINQ's Include() method to request eager loading of the Task object. I suspect that it's where the mistake resides.

```
//TaskController.cs

namespace ProjectManagementAPI.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class TaskController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ProjectManagementDBEntities _context;

        public TaskController(ProjectManagementDBEntities context)
        {
            _context = context;

        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Task> GetAll()
        {
            return _context.Tasks.Include(t => t.Project).ToList();
        }


        [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetTask")]
        public IActionResult GetById(long id)
        {
            var task = _context.Tasks.Include(t => t.Project).FirstOrDefault(t => t.Id == id);
            if (task == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return new ObjectResult(task);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create([FromBody] Task Task)
        {
            if (Task == null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            _context.Tasks.Add(Task);
            _context.SaveChanges();

            return CreatedAtRoute("GetTask", new { id = Task.Id }, Task);
        }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: EF model is ok. Most likely the problem is in serialization due to circular reference between `Project` and `Task`. That's why people usually don't use directly EF objects, but view models/DTOs. You need to find a way to configure serializer to resolve circular references, or manually set to `null` depending on the method `Task.Project` or `Project.Tasks` properties of the result set  before returning it.

Comment: OR, just use a DTO. It's absolutely *amazingly* how many people's problems would just magically dissipate if they stopped binding to entities directly and stop returning entities directly. Entities are for the database. Nothing else.